# custom uitableviewcell label hide/show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell in my table view controller. On my cell there is a label which i want to either show/hide based on the row information. I can easily show/hide the label based on the row information. But is it possible to expand or collapse the height of the tableview cell based on whether that label is present or not? I expect just one row of data for that label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

Attach a [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) to your UITableView's delegate. And implement the above method and set the height depending on if the cell is collapsed or expanded.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (indexPath.row == _rowIndexWithLabel) ? tableView.rowHeight + _heightOfLabel : tableView.rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: Lets say in storyboard my current height of the cell is 80..if i am going to show that additional label, then  i increase the height by 10 ? right?

Comment: also, is there a way to get the current height from storyboard? Then i can just return that...

Answer (score 1):

Use the heightForRowAtIndexPath call to conditionally return 0 or the height, and call reloadItemsAtIndexPath when you have to expand/contract.

Comment: Do not call `-reloadItemsAtIndexPath:`, instead just call `[self.tableView beginUpdates]; [self.tableView endUpdates];` this takes care of animating the cell heights without reloading cells.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Wow I didn't know about this. Any place this is documented?

Comment: `You can also use this method followed by the endUpdates method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell.`

Answer (score 0):

You should implement self-sizing cells.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView;(UITableVIew *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexpath *)indexPath {
    return x.xx; // Whatever your average row height is
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

After this you set up your cell classes with AutoLayout and they will tell the table view what height they will be. If your label does not have content then your cell will adjust and the TableView will reflect that.